# Element-ui $emit in confirm dialog invalid

Tags: vuejs2, element-ui

I tried to get the request sent by the child page from the parent page, but it was unsuccessful。Someone can help me, thank you.

1.parent code

```
<do-more @onreloadtab="reloadTab" :selectFolder="selectFolder"></do-more>
methods: {
  reloadTab: function() {
    console.log('reload')
  }
}
```

2.child code

```
<template>
  <span class="do-more">
    <el-dropdown size="mini" @visible-change="dropdownChange($event)" 
      @command="dropdownCommon($event)" >
      <span class="el-dropdown-link">
        <el-button size="mini" type="text" icon="el-icon-more" 
          class="triggleBtn"></el-button>
      </span>
    <el-dropdown-menu slot="dropdown">
      <el-dropdown-item command="delete">del</el-dropdown-item>
      </el-dropdown-menu>
    </el-dropdown>
  </span>
</template>

methods: {
  delete: function(row) {
    let that = this
    this.$confirm("Are you sure to delete?", "confirm")
      .then((config) => {
        that.$emit('onreloadtab')
      })
      .catch(() => {});
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to:

```
<template>
  <span class="do-more">
    <el-dropdown size="mini" @visible-change="dropdownChange" 
      @command="dropdownCommon" >
      <span class="el-dropdown-link">
        <el-button size="mini" type="text" icon="el-icon-more" 
          class="triggleBtn"></el-button>
      </span>
    <el-dropdown-menu slot="dropdown">
      <el-dropdown-item command="delete">del</el-dropdown-item>
      </el-dropdown-menu>
    </el-dropdown>
  </span>
</template>

methods: {
  dropdownCommon(command) {
    if(command === 'delete'){
      this.$confirm("Are you sure to delete?", "confirm")
      .then((config) => {
        this.$emit('onreloadtab')
      })
      .catch(() => {});
    }
    // other command
  }
}
```

When a dropdown item `el-dropdown-item` is clicked, the `@command` event of `el dropdown` receives the `command` attribute value from `el-dropdown-item`.

You can also use the `@click` event instead of the `command` attribute on the `el-dropdown-item`.

Comment: click can call delete function ,but parent page can not get emit event.
thank you .